# Sharp AR-5516 printer on Linux

Tags: printing, cups, wine

I have a Sharp AR-5516 printer, which has no ppd file on openprinting.org.

We tried to modify the AR-5220 and AR-5316 ppd files to work with our printer without success.

My question:

Is it possible to solve this with wine and the Windows driver?